# Milvus 1.0 failed to start

Tags: mysql, database

`Loading configuration from: /var/lib/milvus/conf/server_config.yaml Supported CPU instruction sets: avx512, avx2, sse4_2 FAISS hook AVX512 Error: failed to open database: Can't construct MySQL connection. Possible reason: out of storage, meta schema is damaged or created by in-compatible Milvus version. Milvus server is going to shut down... Milvus server exit...`

I have tried to start milvus 1.0, however it was not successful.
The log shows the above error.

system: Ubuntu
CPU: 8 c
Memory: 32Gb

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this error is usually because the Milvus container cannot connect to MySQL. You can check the following places:

1. Check whether the MySQL address in the configuration file in Milvus uses "127.0.0.1". Because when Milvus is started in the docker container and MySQL is started on the host, you cannot connect to MySQL on the host using the address 127.0.0.1 in the docker container.
2. Check whether your machine's firewall has any special settings.
3. If it is a cloud server, check whether the security group and access whitelist have been set.